# Why is babel home page different from the editor in the online tool

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

When I learned React to build virtual DOM，I use the editor on babel's website，Why are the two editors turning different code?
[image]

[image]

Why are the two editors turning different code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the editor tool screenshot we can see that the selected option for the "React Runtime" configuration is "Automatic", while Babel's website editor looks like it's using the "Classic" option.

The difference between both is documented in https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx

There is also this [blog post](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html) on React's blog, which explains the reasons behind.